# SQL Server global temp table - Invalid object error

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

```
SELECT  @SqlCmdEnd =',Member_Cd as x_Member_Cd,
            LOD.Val_Seq as x_GroupSort,
            vs.Member_RCID  as x_Org_Key,
            LOD.Val_Cd  as x_Level_Text,
            Type_RCID   as x_Type_RCID  
        into ##VS_Wide'+@l_Random+'
```

We have a dynamic query inside a stored procedure which uses a global temp table as shown above. It is working fine for normal scenarios but during load, concurrency test we are getting an error:

> Invalid object ##VS_Wide12345

`12345` is a random number generated using the below script.

So what could be the possible reason for this error? Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
select @l_Random = replace(right(rand(), 5), '.', '')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @l_Random CHAR(32) = REPLACE(NEWID(), '-', '')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = '
IF OBJECT_ID(''##VS_Wide' + @l_Random + ''') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##VS_Wide' + @l_Random + '

SELECT 1 AS a
INTO ##VS_Wide' + @l_Random + '

SELECT * FROM ##VS_Wide' + @l_Random + '
'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('##VS_WideC016ADF003FD4254B6BBFB5053E9C956') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##VS_WideC016ADF003FD4254B6BBFB5053E9C956

SELECT 1 AS a
INTO ##VS_WideC016ADF003FD4254B6BBFB5053E9C956

SELECT * FROM ##VS_WideC016ADF003FD4254B6BBFB5053E9C956
```